# PHP query result = empty, then div hide

Tags: php, html

I have a calculator function that displays the result when a user enters a query in a div (calcanswer) but often the query is not a calculation request, so the result is "query=" in which query represents the user input, and then nothing behind the = sign. I am wondering whether it is possible to implement a function that hides the div when this happens (i.e. there is no calculation).

PHP:

```
<?php
$a=$_GET['q'];
//$a="1/2";
$add = stripos($a, '+') !== false;
$sub = stripos($a, '-') !== false;
$mul = stripos($a, '*') !== false;
$div = stripos($a, '/') !== false;
if($add){
    $b=explode("+",$a);
    $n1=(float)$b[0];
    $n2=(float)$b[1];
    $n3=$n1+$n2;
}else if($sub){
    $b=explode("-",$a);
    $n1=(float)$b[0];
    $n2=(float)$b[1];
    $n3=$n1-$n2;
} else if($mul){
    $b=explode("*",$a);
    $n1=(float)$b[0];
    $n2=(float)$b[1];
    $n3=$n1*$n2;
} else if($div){
    $b=explode("/",$a);
    $n1=(float)$b[0];
    $n2=(float)$b[1];
    $n3=$n1/$n2;
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="calcanswer"><center>
  <h4 class="card-title pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-7">
  <?= $a."=".$n3 ?>
</h4></center></div>
```

Comment: Hi there.

I am right in saying that someone would put in the $_GET['q'] something along the lines of "1 + 2 ="? If so, what would you do or how are you limiting the user putting in "1 + 2 + 3 ="?

I would allow the user to enter in two numbers and using a drop down list, to select the required operator (-+/*). That way, you don't have to worry about what is on the other side of "=".

The question just needs a little bit more background information, then I can pen a function for you.

Comment: Hi sorry, it is in a search functionality I am working on, so it also shows other results next to it. Hope this clears things up. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to fix it by doing this:

```
<?php
        if(isset($n3)) {
        ?>

        <div class="calcanswer"><center>
          <h4 class="card-title pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-7">
           <?= $a."=".$n3 ?>
        </h4></center></div>

        <?php } ?>
```

I want to thank @Tim Hinz for helping me in such a short amount of time & Jim Grant for taking time out of their day to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET["query"])) {
?>

<div class="calcanswer"><center>
  <h4 class="card-title pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-7">
   <?= $a."=".$n3 ?>
</h4></center></div>

<?php } ?>
```